# Getting error in gemfile while embed youtube video in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

I need to embed youtube videos in my rails application. For that I have added gem ‘**youtube-g**’ in Gemfile.

After that given bundle install.  There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `‘youtube' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

Help me to find out the issue

Comment: Add corresponding part of Gemfile to the question. Looks like problem is in backticks

Answer (score 0):

I think youtube-g is to old since, latest update for the gem after I checked it is 2009 [from this link](https://rubygems.org/gems/youtube-g/versions/0.4.1), alternative step for you to embed youtube video just insert this code below in your view, and change the one that I marked your_youtube_code depend with your logic

```
<iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/<%= your_youtube_code  %>?rel=0&autoplay=<%= params[:autoplay] || 0 %>' frameborder='0' mozallowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen oallowfullscreen msallowfullscreen width="1280" height="720"></iframe>
```